# how Dispose / close stream of "TiffBitmapDecoder"

Tags: c#, io, tiff

```
var filePath= @"c:\user\image.tif";
TiffBitmapDecoder TifDec = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(path), BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
File.Delete(pathFile);
```

is throw exception "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'c:\user\image.tif' because it is being used by another process."

this code not working

```
var filePath = @"c:\user\image.tif";
TiffBitmapDecoder TifDec = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(filePath), BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
TifDec.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
TifDec.Dispatcher.DisableProcessing();
while (!TifDec.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished)
    Thread.Sleep(10);
File.Delete(filePath);
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vFy.png)

Comment: Just for the record, try to avoid randomly calling things like `TifDec.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown` until something sticks. You should understand the contract of the method call rather than relying just on the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it seems that there is no way to do this cleanly.

The stream is closed in the finalizer, but there's no way to force that code to run. It's also closed in the `CloseStream` method, but that's internal.

So avoid using the `Uri` overload. Instead, open the file yourself, and use the `Stream` overload of `TiffBitmapDecoder`. You can then dispose the stream at will, and delete the file as soon as you release the stream. Of course, you shouldn't use the `TiffBitmapDecoder` after you release the stream.

If you want to delete the file even sooner, just create a memory stream, fill it with data from `File.ReadAllBytes`, and use that for the decoder.